# 100,0000 million rest api call to be made in python

Tags: python, twisted

I have a list with 300 million url's .I need to invoke async rest api calls with this url's.I dont require the responses.
    I tried to implement this with twisted.when the list grows with more than 1000 url's I am getting error.Please suggest me how this could be achieved

```
Please find my code 

# start of my program
from twisted.web import client
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
#list of urls to be invoked
urls = [
 'http://test.com/apiname/?s=85465&ts=1370591808', 
 'http://test.com/apiname/?s=85465&ts=1370591808', 
 'http://test.com/apiname/?s=85465&ts=1370591808', 
 'http://test.com/apiname/?s=85465&ts=1370591808', 
 'http://test.com/apiname/?s=85465&ts=1370591808', 
 'http://test.com/apiname/?s=85465&ts=1370591808', 
 'http://test.com/apiname/?s=85465&ts=1370591808', 
 'http://test.com/apiname/?s=85465&ts=1370591808'
]
#list of urls

#the call back
def finish(results):
    for result in results:
    print 'GOT PAGE', len(result), 'bytes'
    reactor.stop()


waiting = [client.getPage(url) for url in urls]
defer.gatherResults(waiting).addCallback(finish)

reactor.run()
```

Comment: What kind of number shall "100,0000 million" be?! What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

The first issue, given the source provided, is that 300 million URL strings will take a lot of RAM.  Keep in mind each string has overhead above and beyond the bytes and the combination of the strings into a list will likely require re-allocations.

In addition, I think the subtle bug here is that you're trying to accumulate the results into a list with waiting = [ ... ].  I suspect you really meant that you wanted an iterator that fed gatherResults().

To remedy both these ills, write your file into "urls.txt" and try the following instead *(also drop the bit with urls = [...])*:

```
import sys.stdin
waiting = (client.getPage(url.strip() for url in sys.stdin)
defer.gatherResults(waiting).addCallback(finish)

reactor.run()
```

Simply run using **python script.py <urls.txt**

The difference between [...] and (...) is quite large.  [...] runs the ... part immediately, creating a giant list of the results; (...) creates a generator that will yield one result for each iteration in the ...

*Note: I have not had a chance to test any of that (I don't use Twisted much) but from what you posted, these changes should help your RAM issue*

Comment: I am also very new to twisted and python ,can I invoke this without addCallback

Comment: You still don't want to issue all of these requests in parallel.  If 300 million URLs take a lot of memory, 300 million HTTP requests and responses take even more.  Consider combining this answer with the information in this old blog post of mine - http://as.ynchrono.us/2006/05/limiting-parallelism_22.html

Comment: Interesting -- so gatherResults() does the entire generation in parallel with no throttling?  I'm surprised Twisted doesn't have something built in like the parallel() function you posted.  (But, as noted, I haven't used much Twisted.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply,Jean, in this specific requirement,I don't need a response back from the url's , it is just fire and forget.Hence to improve the preformacne can you please suggest me options when using twisted